# elementRef.style.top = "100px" doesn't work

Tags: css, angular

I want to move the position of a component using elementRef.
My code below seems pretty reasonable - but doesn't work. Why?

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      let element = this.elementRef.nativeElement
      element.style.color = "red" // WORKS!
      element.style.top = "100px" // NO EFFECT!
  }
```

here's a link to my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qlzkkc?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

top, bottom properties work only for positioned elements. So by adding any position property to it can fix the issue.

eg.

```
element.style.position = "relative";
```

Answer (score 3):

This is css issue. If you add, for example, `element.style.position = "absolute"`, you'll see that `top = "100px"` works.