# Using [style] to position element not working

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble positioning a div using [style].
I feel like i've followed the instructions of related posts/blogs, but am not getting the correct results. (to position the div at 100,100).
Can anyone see what is wrong with the code below?

Full sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4kryx?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template:
  `<div 
  [style.left]="left"
  [style.top]="top"
  [style.color]="color">Hello!</div>`
})
export class HelloComponent {
  top = "100px" // does nothing
  left = "100px" // does nothing
  color = "red" // works!
}
```

Comment: You don't set `position: relative` as suggested in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50142454/1009922)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the position as well.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template:
  `<div 
  [style.left]="left"
  [style.top]="top"
  [style.position]="position"
  [style.color]="color">Hello!</div>`
})
export class HelloComponent {
  top = "100px";
  left = "100px";
  position = "relative";
  color = "red";
}
```

See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-45x1px?file=app/hello.component.ts